# TFS API Changeset branch

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I’ve trying to extract the branch history from a changeset, following [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsversioncontrol/thread/3bd217c0-0981-4c79-b8ed-a48c4b33b596) article.  However, I’ve noticed that a Changeset has a property called IsBranch, which is not the way that the article describes to check whether the changeset is a branch.

What is the difference between the following checks:

```
VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Changeset cs = vcs.GetChangeset(changeset.ChangesetId);

Console.WriteLine("Changeset: {0}", cs.ChangesetId);

// Get History
foreach (var change in cs.Changes)
{
     if (change.Item.IsBranch)
     {
     }
```

And

```
VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Changeset cs = vcs.GetChangeset(changeset.ChangesetId);

Console.WriteLine("Changeset: {0}", cs.ChangesetId);

// Get History
foreach (var change in cs.Changes)
{
     if ((change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Branch) == ChangeType.Branch)                    
     {
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

The IsBranch property of the Item class is new in 2010, so the second way is the way that you would have done it in previous versions of TFS.

[2010 Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item.aspx)

[2008 Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: If that's the case then how come I have situations where the two checks don't match up?

Comment: I don't know, maybe there is a bug in the code for IsBranch or ChangeType and they use different criteria to set the property. Which one is giving you the results you expect?

Comment: IsBranch always seems to be False

Comment: I tested it out myself and you are right, it does appear to always be false, at least when accessing the Item class from a Change object. So I would use the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

To get TFS to set the value for the `item.IsBranch` property you need to tell the `VersionControlServer` that you want the item's branch info by passing the `GetItemsOptions.IncludeBranchInfo` flag when calling `GetItem()`.

**Example:**

```
using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(uri))
{
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
    var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    var item = vcs.GetItem("$/Proj/Main/", VersionSpec.Latest, DeletedState.Any, GetItemsOptions.IncludeBranchInfo);
}
```